# If fluid flow is in units $m/s$, what units are $div$ in?

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, vector-fields, units

Imagine a fluid flow given by the formula $\mathbf{v} = x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j}$, this is a simple radial flow outward and the dimensions would be length/time: At a given point, what is the velocity of fluid through that point.  Let's assume units are $m/s$.

What units are divergence of the velocity in? For example, at the point $(1,1)$, we have $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{v} = 2$.  Dimensional analysis suggests that dimensions of this are 1/time, independent of the units of length but dependent on the units of time.  In our case, the units would be *per second*.

So, what does it mean to say that divergence of the velocity at that point is "2 per second".  Two *what* per second?

I understand qualitatively that divergence is a measure of source [positive] or sink [negative] at that point, but I'm trying to develop this further into a *quantitative* understanding: what does a divergence of velocity being 2 mean? And this requires dimensions and units.

I've tried a few options but none work:

- "div n per second" does *not* mean something multiplies by $n$ every second, because for a constant field, divergence is zero
- it doesn't seem possible to mean something increases by $n$ every second: What unitless quantity could be increasing?
- I tried working ideas "If a known particle of water travels through a patch with div 2 for 1 second, then something goes up by 2" but couldn't get any to work.

Comment: I've tagged this question electromagnetism as well, because an answer in electromagnetic units will be just as helpful

Comment: Typically $x$ and $y$ have units of length and $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$ are unitless. Therefore, your example vector $\vec F = x\hat{\imath} + y\hat{\jmath}$ has units of length, not units of length per second. The divergence has units of inverse length, so your $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec F$ is the unitless number $2$, as you have already discovered.

Comment: As an aside, $\operatorname{div}$ is an operator which means that it has an argument, much the same way sine and cosine operate on a parameter (like an angle). When you write "div=2" and "divergence" (without qualifiers), there is a gap in the context (i.e., divergence *of what*?). It is possible that this lack of common usage may be the cause of some of the downvotes, but I don't know (it definitely confused me for a little while, I'd even commented on it, but since deleted it).

Answer (score 4):

To understand the seemingly weird unit of $\text{div}\ \mathbf{F}$
this [definition of the divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition) will help:
$$\text{div}\ \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}_0)=
  \lim_{V\to 0}\frac{\oint_{S(V)}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot d\mathbf{S}}{V}$$

where $\mathbf{F}$ in your case is a velocity field,
$V$ is a small volume around $\mathbf{r}_0$,
$S(V)$ is the closed surface area of this volume,
and $d\mathbf{S}$ is a surface area element.

Now let us look at the fraction on the right side of this equation.
The numerator $\oint_{S(V)}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot d\mathbf{S}$
has dimension of velocity $\cdot$ area, or volume/time.
(It gives quite intuitively the outflow of the fluid out of
volume $V$, measurable e.g. in $\text{m}^3/\text{s}$.)
And the denominator $V$ obviously has dimension of volume.
Hence $\text{div}\ \mathbf{F}$ has the dimension of volume/time/volume,
measurable e.g. in $\text{m}^3/\text{s}/\text{m}^3$.
Just keep this unit in your intuition, because
canceling the $\text{m}^3$ here (resulting in $1/\text{s}$)
does not help much.

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be correct, then, that if $F = x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j}$ m/s, and $\text{div} F = 2 m^3/s/m^3$ everywhere, then for any region with volume 1 $m^3$, the net inflow is 2 $m^3/s$?  In that respect, div takes a _**velocity**_ field and gives us a _rate of net **volume** flow per volume_.

Comment: @SRobertJames Yes, that's it, except that it is the outflow, not inflow.

Comment: I think I get this for the integral formula you used.  Can you explain how the differential formula $div = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}$ goes from linear meters ($F$) to cubic meters ($div$)? Where are we cubing the units?

Comment: @SRobertJames There is no cubing. It goes from meter/second (F) to 1/second (div F).

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\nabla$ is shorthand for,
$$\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat{y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat{z}.$$
since $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$ are all unitless, then the units are taken from whatever unit $x$ has. More specifically, the spatial derivative has units of inverse length,
$$\left[\nabla\right]\sim\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]=\frac{1}{\text{length}},$$
If you are considering temporal derivatives instead, you have units of inverse time,
$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right]=\frac{1}{\text{time}}.$$
More fun is when you are taking the derivative with respect to velocity (which happens in the Euler-Lagrange equation!),
$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right]=\frac{1}{\text{length / time}}=\frac{\text{time}}{\text{length}}.$$

Since $\nabla$ is an operator, the resultant unit depends on the object it acts on. In the case of the fluid flow example you provided, it would be,
$$\left[\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right]=\frac{\text{length}/\text{time}}{\text{length}}=\frac{1}{\text{time}}.$$
In fluid dynamics, the term with divergence/gradient operators typically have some coefficients attached to it, so it would be things like "mass density per second" (which would be the [mass flow rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate)) or when multiplying this term with a velocity, as you would find in the Navier-Stokes (hereafter, NS) equations, you get an acceleration:
$$\left[\mathbf{v}\left(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}\right)\right]=\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}}\times\frac{1}{\text{time}}=\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}^2}$$
which you should expect, since you have a time-derivative of a velocity in the NS equation, which is, of course, the acceleration.

The same thing happens when you look at the gradient of pressure,
$$\left[\nabla p\right]=\frac{\text{mass / length / time}^2}{\text{length}}=\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{time}^2\text{ length}^2}$$
such that when multiplied by the inverse of the density, yields an acceleration:
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\left[\nabla p\right]=\frac{\text{length}^3}{\text{mass}}\times\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{time}^2\text{ length}^2}=\frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}^2}$$